# Admob is not displayed during the app's first execution. 2

Tags: cordova, admob

I made an Android app with Phonegap (Cordova 2.5.0). And I put admob in my app using this plugin. ( https://github.com/sainttex/PhoneGap-Android-Native-AdMob )

Admob is displayed in my app. But there's a problem. During the first execution, admob's not showing up. After closing the app and re-starting it, admob is displayed. From the second execution onwards, admob is displayed.

If I don't use the app for a while (about one hour), then run the app, the problem comes up again.

What can I do to fix problem?

Bellow is my code.

[MainActivity.java code]

```
package com.***.*******;    

import com.google.ads.*;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout; 
//import android.view.Menu;




public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    private static final String AdMob_Ad_Unit = "*************";
    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit); 
        LinearLayout layout = super.root;
        layout.addView(adView); 
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(request);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }

}
```

[AndroidManifest.xml code]

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this ***after*** the `super.loadUrl("------");`

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit); 
        LinearLayout layout = super.root;
        layout.addView(adView); 
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Install cordova admob plugin.

```
cordova plugin add com.admob.AdmobPlugin
```

Then add this code.

```
function onDeviceReady() {  
    admobAd.initBanner("ca-app-pub-1738093038576474/9839543541",admobAd.AD_SIZE.BANNER.width,admobAd.AD_SIZE.BANNER.height);//ios Interstitial  
    admobAd.showBanner(admobAd.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER);  
}  
document.addEventListener('deviceready',onDeviceReady, false);
```